# How to select random item from drop-down list using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, cypress

In the site: https://www.testandquiz.com/selenium/testing.html there is a drop down located here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EukO7.png)

The html is like the following:

```html
<select id="testingDropdown">
<option id="automation" value="Automation">Automation Testing</option>
<option id="performance" value="Performance">Performance Testing</option>
<option id="manual" value="Manual">Manual Testing</option>
<option id="database" value="Database">Database Testing</option>
</select>
```

I would like to:

1. Click on the mentioned drop down
2. Count the number of items
3. Select the random item from the list

How to deal with that usuing cypress ?

I tried by the following but the test failed

```js
describe('Cypress.io tests', function() {
    it('Open cypress.io page', function() {
      var cypressPage = 'https://www.testandquiz.com/selenium/testing.html'
      
cy.visit(cypressPage)
     cy.xpath("//[@id='testingDropdown']").click();

    })
  })
```

Comment: What exactly ended with an error? What seems to be an issue? In your code I do not see an attempt to choose random value.

Answer (score 2):

So for example we have a select with three options.

HTML code:

```
<select id="selectId">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

javascript code:

```
  //Random int number generator between min and max
  function getRandomInt(min, max){      
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;    
  } 

  cy.get(`#selectId> option`) // we get the select/option by finding the select by id
  .then(listing => {        
    const randomNumber = getRandomInt(0, listing.length-1); //generate a rendom number between 0 and length-1. In this case 0,1,2
    cy.get(`#selectId> option`).eq(randomNumber).then(($select) => {              //choose an option randomly
      const text = $select.text()       //get the option's text. For ex. "A"
      cy.get(`#selectId`).select(text)       // select the option on UI
    });    
  })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use .get() to reach your element?
With .children() you can get the amount of elements within your dropdown.

```
cy.get('#testingDropdown').children()
```

Or do you want it as a variable?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: Didn't have enough reputation. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

A bit late to the party.

Cypress will not allow you to use click() for select elements. You will need to use select function for this.
You will  also need two xpaths:

1. For the drop down element
2. For the drop down options that will be selected at random.

This is the working code

```
describe('Cypress.io tests', function() {
it('Open cypress.io page', function() {
  var cypressPage = 'https://www.testandquiz.com/selenium/testing.html';
  
cy.visit(cypressPage);
   // Get the array of options
   cy.xpath('//*[@id="testingDropdown"]//option').then(($elements) => {
  const randomOption = Math.floor(Math.random() * $elements.length);
  // select option from drop down
  cy.xpath('//*[@id="testingDropdown"]').select(`${$elements[randomOption].innerText}`);
  cy.log(`random option selected is ${$elements[randomOption].innerText}}`);
})
})
```